# How to unpack a python dictionary in bash script

Tags: bash, python

My python script returns a dictionary to bash script as follows:

```
dictionary=$(/path/to/my-script.py --my-profiles setenv)
```

```
my-script.py

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My script')
    parser.add_argument('--my-profiles', dest="profiles", 
                        type=str,
                        default='')
    parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.profiles == "setenv":
        print({'SOME_ENV': '1', 'SOME_OTHER_ENV': '0'})
```

My `dictionary` variable in bash has the dictionary. I want to unpack this dictionary and access both the key and value of each item.

Comment: You can't. A better solution is to modify your script to return the values in a format that is easier to parse in bash, or just write your entire script in Python rather than switching between two languages. If you can modify the script to output JSON, you could possibly use a tool like `jq` to parse out the values in bash.

Comment: @larsks let's say my python script is outputting JSON format. `print(json.({'SOME_ENV': '1', 'SOME_OTHER_ENV': '0'}))` How can I unpack and retrieve key and values

Comment: You'll want to spend some time reading about the [`jq` command](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). There are several examples in the tutorial. Given your example in the previous command, `my-script.py | jq -r 'keys[]'` would get you a simple list of keys, and `my-script.py | jq -r '.SOME_ENV'` would get you the value of `SOME_ENV`.